# How to write MySQL query for If Exists Update Else Insert?

Tags: mysql

I tried to write MySQL Insert and update query in one query but seems it not working can someone please explain me what is the error of following code, thank you..

```
IF EXISTS 
    (
        SELECT * 
        FROM contact 
        WHERE account_id='".$_GET['acc']."' AND contact_id='".$_GET['con']."'
    )
    UPDATE contact SET 
    category='".$_GET['cat']."',  shares='".$_GET['sh']."'
    WHERE account_id='".$_GET['acc']."' AND contact_id='".$_GET['con']."'
ELSE
    INSERT INTO contact 
    (account_id,contact_id, category, shares)
    VALUES ('".$_GET['acc']."', '".$_GET['con']."', '".$_GET['cat']."', '".$_GET['sh']."')
```

Comment: Can you tell us what was the expected result and what you did get ?

Answer (score 0):

REPLACE works exactly like INSERT, except that if an old row in the table has the same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted.

[See REPLACE syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace.html)